# Authenticate Users and use Graph API using Azure AD, ReactJS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, reactjs, passport.js, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an project app created using NodeJS + ReactJS and all that I want is to use the Azure AD to authenticate the user and get his data like name, groups, picture, occupation, etc, using the Graph API from Azure.

I already have the Azure AD and the App properly configured on Azure Portal. Including the permissions delegations and all these staff.

I'm trying to understand how is best way to do that but without success. I've been trying to find on google, StackOverflow, Microsoft Documentations, even projects samples.

Some samples have worked, but no one of them I could understand and put into my project to work as a production App.

**I've used this for Authenticate the user, but the returned AccessToken is not valid to call the Graph API:**

```
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
    redirectUrl: config.creds.returnURL,
    realm: config.creds.realm,
    clientID: config.creds.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.creds.clientSecret,
    oidcIssuer: config.creds.issuer,
    identityMetadata: config.creds.identityMetadata,
    skipUserProfile: config.creds.skipUserProfile,
    responseType: config.creds.responseType,
    responseMode: config.creds.responseMode,
    allowHttpForRedirectUrl: config.creds.allowHttpForRedirectUrl
  },
  function(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) {
    console.log(accessToken);
    profile = profile._json;
    if (!profile.email) {
      return done(new Error("No email found"), null);
    }
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          // "Auto-registration"
          users.push(profile);
          return done(null, profile);
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    });
  }
));
```

**And this one gives me right AccessToken to use the Graph API, but I cannot understand how to use it instead of the Passport:**

```
function createAuthorizationUrl(state) {
  var authorizationUrl = templateAuthzUrl.replace('<client_id>', sampleParameters.clientId);
  authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl.replace('<redirect_uri>',redirectUri);
  authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl.replace('<state>', state);
  authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl.replace('<resource>', resource);
  return authorizationUrl;
}

// Clients get redirected here in order to create an OAuth authorize url and redirect them to AAD.
// There they will authenticate and give their consent to allow this app access to
// some resource they own.
app.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
  crypto.randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) {
    var token = buf.toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');

    res.cookie('authstate', token);
    var authorizationUrl = createAuthorizationUrl(token);

    res.redirect(authorizationUrl);
  });
});

// After consent is granted AAD redirects here.  The ADAL library is invoked via the
// AuthenticationContext and retrieves an access token that can be used to access the
// user owned resource.
app.get('/getAToken', function(req, res) {
  if (req.cookies.authstate !== req.query.state) {
    res.send('error: state does not match');
  }
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
  authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(req.query.code, redirectUri, resource, sampleParameters.clientId, sampleParameters.clientSecret, function(err, response) {
    var message = '';
    if (err) {
      message = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
    }
    message += 'response: ' + JSON.stringify(response);

    if (err) {
      res.send(message);
      return;
    }

    // Later, if the access token is expired it can be refreshed.
    authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithRefreshToken(response.refreshToken, sampleParameters.clientId, sampleParameters.clientSecret, resource, function(refreshErr, refreshResponse) {
      if (refreshErr) {
        message += 'refreshError: ' + refreshErr.message + '\n';
      }
      message += 'refreshResponse: ' + JSON.stringify(refreshResponse);

      res.send(message); 
    }); 
  });
});
```

If anyone could help me with some real app sample, video or something, will be very good. I'm losing my mind to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The passport's `OIDCStrategy` follows [Authorize access to web applications using OpenID Connect and Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code) to authenticate & authorize users. And if you need the access for resources, you still need to complete the step of [Use the authorization code to request an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token).

I add some code snippets based on the [openid connection sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect):

The return route function will get the use the `code` to acquire the access token and save into user seesion object.

```
app.post('/auth/openid/return',
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function (req, res) {
    let option = {
      method:'POST',
      uri:'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token',
      headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      form:{
        grant_type:'authorization_code',
        client_id:'<client_id>',
        resource:'https://graph.windows.net',
        client_secret:'<secret_key>',
        code:req.body.code,
        redirect_uri:'http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return'
      }
    }
    console.log(option);
    request(option,function(err,res,body){
      req.user.access_token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
    })

    // log.info('We received a return from AzureAD.');
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

The route '/me' is to sample to use access token to require resourece.

```
app.get('/me',ensureAuthenticated ,function(req,response){
  request.get("https://graph.windows.net/<tenant_id>/me?api-version=1.5", {
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + req.user.access_token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }, function(err, res, body){
    if(err){
      console.log("err: " + err);
    }
    else{
      console.log("res: " + res);
      response.send(res);
    }
  });
});
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Gary! Thanks for the reply...
Before see your answer, I got the results using the adal-node instead of the Passport with this method:
`authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode()`
But now, I have another WebAPI configured on the Azure and I still have problems to call the Methods of this API. I changed the resource parameter of the adal-node method and I got a valid token to call my WebAPI, but now the graph is not working with this token.

Comment: My question is: Do I need to get 2 different tokens to use my WebAPI and the Graph API? Is it OK if I use the "acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode" to authenticate the user and call the Graph and use the "acquireTokenWithClientCredentials" to require the token for use to call the WebAPI?

Comment: Change the `resource` parameter for different resources in these sample https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs#authorization-code. E.G. use `resource = "https://graph.windows.net"` to acquire the access token for the Azure AD graph resource.

Comment: Perfect! But, it's a good practice to do? Like: use the adal to authenticate the user and then create one method to get accessTokens for different resources? I created a method which receive a resource as parameter and call the adal method to get the token from azure and it's working very well now. But I don't really know if it's a good practice to do. What do you think?

Comment: It is designed by OAuth 2.0, for security reason.